# How do I get HTMLDOC launched from a CGI-script?

Tags: html, pdf, cgi

I have a CGI-script which produces a `.pdf` file from the HTML page. My problem is that when it is launched from the Web Browser, there is no creation of the `.pdf` document.

What I have done so far:

- chmod settings set to above recommended (777)
- tested normal output on the file from the script, which works fine
- when running locally on the server from the command line, the `.cgi` script works

Why does the script not work when run from the web browser?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::HTMLDoc;
use CGI;
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html><head><title>test</title></head>";
print "<body>";

my $htmldoc->set_html_content(qq~<html><body>A PDF file</body></html>~);
my $pdf = $htmldoc->generate_pdf() or die($!);
$pdf->to_file('/var/www/tom.pdf');
print "</body></html>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Where do you send the generated file to the browser?

Note that you cannot embed PDF in HTML; you must either

- put the file in a place where your web server will deliver it and send a link to the file to the browser
- or set the content type to `application/pdf` and just return the file (without any HTML tags around it).

Answer (score 1):

The mostly likely cause is that `/var/www` is not writable to the apache process (or whatever web server you are using), so if you run it from the command line - with your user's permissions - it succeeds, but when called from a web browser the web server runs it with its own (very limited) permissions and then the writing fails.

You need to first - check the return code of the `to_file` method to see if the writing was successful, and secondly - write to a directory where the web server is allowed to write, such as `/var/tmp`.